# Java и USB передача данных - Java SE

Tags: java, usb, request

Нужно сделать приложение. Его суть такова:
Есть микроконтроллер (**TTL**) - он подключается через USB к ПК. Микроконтроллер передаёт данные на пк - цифра.

Так вот. Как мне приложением на Java получать эти данные?

**P.S.** Подключение происходит не через COM порт - Взял библиотеку jsr80 и она не показывала что это устройство подключено через COM.

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне такое реализовать?

RXTX:

```
import gnu.io.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;

public class SimpleRead implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {
    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static Enumeration portList;

    InputStream inputStream;
    SerialPort serialPort;
    Thread readThread;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                if (portId.getName().equals("COM4")) {
                    //                if (portId.getName().equals("/dev/term/a")) {
                    SimpleRead reader = new SimpleRead();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public SimpleRead() {
        try {
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
            inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        } catch (PortInUseException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        readThread = new Thread(this);
        readThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        switch (event.getEventType()) {
            case SerialPortEvent.BI:
            case SerialPortEvent.OE:
            case SerialPortEvent.FE:
            case SerialPortEvent.PE:
            case SerialPortEvent.CD:
            case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
            case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
            case SerialPortEvent.RI:
            case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
                break;
            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];

                try {
                    while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                        System.out.println(numBytes);
                    }
                    System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

JSSC:

```
import jssc.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Jssc {

        private static SerialPort serialPort;

        private static byte[][] requests = {{00, 00, 01}, {00, 00, 02}, {00, 00, 03}};
        private static int requestNum = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4");
            try {
                serialPort.openPort();
                serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                serialPort.setEventsMask(SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);
                serialPort.addEventListener(new EventListener());
                serialPort.writeBytes(requests[requestNum]);
            }
            catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }

        private static class EventListener implements SerialPortEventListener {

            public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
                if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() == 2){
                    try {
                        if(requestNum == 0){
                            byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(2);
                        /*Пост обработка и вывод на форму*/
                            serialPort.writeBytes(requests[++requestNum]);
                        }
                        else if(requestNum == 1){
                            byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(2);
                        /*Пост обработка и вывод на форму*/
                            serialPort.writeBytes(requests[++requestNum]);
                        }
                        else if(requestNum == 2){
                            byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(2);
                        /*Пост обработка и вывод на форму*/
                            serialPort.writeBytes(requests[0]);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что подключение происходит "не через COM порт"? Многие USB-устройства внутри себя имеют rs232 и фактически, общение происходит именно через него. Что ваш код и делает, ожидая устройства с именем "COM4". Если говорить вообще о USB, то в нем есть масса режимов передачи данных, уточните вопрос тем, в каком именно режиме происходит общение.

Comment: А где уверенность, что проблема в java-коде? Контроллер точно передаёт данные? Чем-то другим его работу проверить можно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Решение** - всё дело было в самом устройстве. Нужно было поменять подключение USB проводов.